# how to reference foreign key in Entity when separating domain model from persistence model

Tags: kotlin, foreign-keys, domain-driven-design, entity, hexagonal-architecture

I am trying out a hexagonal architecture project and separating domain model from persistence model. But I am struggling in the case when I have to reference the foreign key of another entity in the persistence model.

I have a Customer entity that looks like this and its persistence model counterpart

```
class Customer(val customerId: String, val name: String) {
}

@Entity(name = "customer")
data class CustomerEntity(
    var customerId: String,
    var name: String,
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) var id: Long = -1
)
```

the `customerId` is supposed to be the business id and the entity counterpart has additional its own database id.

Now I have another another entity *Report* that references the customer

```
class Report(val reportId: String, val date: LocalDate, val customerId: String) {
}

@Entity
data class ReportEntity(val reportId: String,
                             val date: LocalDate,
                             val customerId: String, // what should be saved here? the persistence Id (Long) of the customer or its business ID (String)?
                             @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
                             var id: Long = -1)
```

If I go with saving the persistence ID of the customer, then I would have to first fetch it from the database, which means I need to query the Customer table from within the Report component. But these two are two separate bounded contexts and I am not sure if this is the right solution or there is a modeling problem here.

Comment: Why did you define a separate ID for the customer? The identity field is a part of the entity in domain-driven design. There is no need to hide it in the domain model. Why did you separate the persistence model from the domain model?

Comment: The primary key is an infrastructure-specific concept that should not be published at the domain layer. You might want to have a separate primary key / cluster index key than the natural key for performance reasons depending on what the actual NK values are and how they can be best walked by the underlying infrastructure.

Comment: @ArwynFr I agree that performance issues like indexing should be hidden but when use cases don't care about your primary key then you created a concept that's not going to be used. In the best case, it would be used for query issues. For that matter, you can use CQRS to handle such problems. A separate model to optimize queries. But does he have performance issues? Is this necessary?

Comment: the reason I added another id for the persistence model, was to be as flexible as possible for the future and also I often heard that no UUIDs should be used in database tables as primary keys. Thanks for the suggestions using CQRS for performance issues. I never did it, but I might use it here in this project if I need it.

Comment: Whether the OP should or should not use a separate primary key from the natural key was beyond the scope of the question, but I'll toss my 2 cents in there:

If the source of truth is external, then you should not reuse externally generated identifiers as primary keys. If the identifier is string-based it will cause performance problems and you should use an integer surrogate key. If the key is numeric, you don't know when the external system is going to change their formats. You would be putting a dependency on the two systems infrastructure layers.

Comment: If you are the source of truth for the entity, you may reuse and expose the integer RDBMS PK as a natural key. This is what most legacy or small services do. But as a tradeoff your application will need a refactor to move away from a monolithic RDBMS. If you need to scale, then implement an id generation service and treat the natural key as externally generated.

Comment: @ArwynFr there is no external system. The project I will be building up from scratch but I want to use this experience and try out best practices I never did before, e.g. ddd, hexagonal architecture (and maybe cqrs). Though I don't want microservices but a monolith for now with one database (or separate databases if it makes sense?!).
So if I understand you correctly then I should use the same a numeric ID for domain and persistence, because all data is in one monolith project and no external source of truth.
From your answer it still sounds like a tradeoff and not the optimal solution.

Comment: So is there any optimal solution? Maybe if I introduce a new concept that I am missing here? Or change anything in the domain model?

Comment: There is no such thing as an optimal solution. Software architecture is always a tradeoff. You said you want a monolith *for now*, which means you consider refactoring later. You can expose the integer PK and even remove the domain layer to write less code now, but scaling your application with increased traffic will require a very costly refactor. Using a surrogate key will make your application cheaper to scale, with a cost of added complexity now. It's up to you to consider which way is more worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you don't have performance issues, you can get rid of the generated ID and use the CustomerId only.

But if you insist on having a separate ID, you will want to have the generated ID as the reference key because it's better for the performance again. On the other hand, you should consider use cases that query the Reports. Are they filtering Reports by CustomerId?

If the answer is "No", you won't have any issues because the use cases don't need the CustomerId.

But, if the answer is "Yes", then you have three options:

1. you can bring both IDs to the Report model. In this way, you have all the information that you need on the Report model. But be aware that the Information must be unmodifiable (like these IDs because they are not going to be updated). Because any update on this information will break your data.
2. you can duplicate the information of the Customer that the Report needs to know about. You must duplicate and manage it via integration events (CRUD events).
3. Pull data from the Customer context. In this way, you don't need to duplicate data but you will depend on Customer context.

On the first two options, you won't depend on Customer context to pull data from but they are harder to apply, especially for the second option.

The third option is easier to apply but at the cost of coupling.

Comment: I dont really understand your second point, what do you mean duplicate it? I only need to store the customerId to retrieve reports for a specific customer. But it seems the best option would be to omit the technical persistence ID an just have the same id in persistence layer and domain layer.

Comment: `CustomerId` is a string-based column. Using it as a primary key will cause performance problems when joining tables.

Comment: The second option talks about having a Customer table in the Record context. The data is a copy of Customer table in the Customer context.

Answer (score 0):

> If I go with saving the persistence ID of the customer, then I would have to first fetch it from the database, which means I need to query the Customer table from within the Report component. But these two are two separate bounded contexts and I am not sure if this is the right solution or there is a modeling problem here.

If your two bounded context share the same persistance layer, then it is ok for your persistence layer to query the Customer table to resolve the primary key from the natural key.

If your two bounded context have separate persistance layers, then you need to maintain a copy of the customers information in the persistance layer of the report context. Let's call them `Customer.Customer` (source of truth in the customer context) and `Report.Customer` (copy in the report context). These models can have different structures, this is called [a polysemic domain model](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html).

The customers are expected to have a different primary key in both persistance layer. When persisting the report, your persistance layer can query the `Report.Customer` table to resolve the primary key from the natural key. You will also need some mechanism to synchronize data from the source of truth to the copy. Do not do the copy at the persistence level (database-to-database) or you will be creating some dependency at the infrastructure level. Prefer to read data from the interface of the Customer service because it is more stable and usually versioned.

Comment: yes currently they do share the same database, it is a monolith project. thanks for your answer!